# How to do a transaction with two collections on Azure CosmosDB

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a question about transaction on Azure CosmosDB (with SQL API) where I have to edit two items on collection A and create other item on collection B.

I’m developing a project where there are exchange of points. So I have users with status of their points and I have to save the transaction for history. On a SQL database, I start a transactions, do the operation of update user A balance, update user B balance and create a new row on tickets with all details of operation and if it is good, end the transaction. But I have dudes about how to do on Azure CosmosDB. I have a collection where there are users with their balance, and other collection with tickets. So, with stored procedure, I can update user A and user B because both are on the same collection and if some of them fail to update, the collection isn’t edited (as transaction of SQL database), but, how to create the new ticket? Because If I have understood the documentation correctly, it works on same collection, but it doesn’t work with different collections.

Could you give me some advice about how to do it in order to do the 3 operations on the same transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CosmosDB only supports transactions within the same partition.

This means that you cannot have cross containers transactions and you also cannot have transaction between 2 documents with different partition key values.

Comment: Ok, and your opinion, do you reorganize the content on same collection and same partition? (i think it isn't good) or do you give the transaction behavior by code on the server? Thank you

Comment: If you need something to execute transactionally in Cosmos then you need to make sure it all lives in the same container and the same partition key value. Unless all your documents are in the same containers and same exact partition there is nothing you can do to execute this transactionally.

Comment: @cansado2930 you can always use a Saga.

Comment: @NickChapsas Can u provide a reference to the same in official documents please.